# Having trouble using newly generated token making API calls. PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED?

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am currently able to generate a token from Docusign's API.

I am using the python wrapper `docusign-esign`.

```
{
'access_token': <JWT token>, 
'data': None, 
'expires_in': '3600', 
'refresh_token': None, 
'scope': None, 
'token_type': 'Bearer'
}
```

For Developers: API and Integration Key Information

Using

- Implicit Grant
- RSA Keypairs
- redirect URI set
- status LIVE

`BASE_URL='https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'`

`OAUTH_BASE_URL='account-d.docusign.com'`

I was using the envelope API to get envelope status with auth header as

`'Authorization Bearer <JWT token>'`

I get the following 400 error:

```
{
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. Invalid account specified for user."
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The public ID, integrator key, API Account ID and API Username are all separate IDs and are used at a different moment when making API calls. This has caused me a huge amount of frustration when dealing with the API.

To help clarify (this is specific to python's wrapper for Docusign):

when using `request_jwt_user_token`

it requires

- `client_id` -- integrator key
- `user_id` -- ID you want to impersonate, which can be found in the admin page > users > API Username (which is a UUID)
- `oauth_host_name` -- `account-d.docusign.com` for dev or `account.docusign.com` for production
- `private_key_bytes` -- the RSA Keypairs in the file (private key)
- `scopes` -- typically `signature impersonate` for JWT implicit grant

then when using the `EnvelopeAPI.create_envelope` it required an `account_id`, which was not the `client_id` nor `user_id`.  The `account_id` for me was the API Account ID for in For Developers: API and Integration Key Information. So either copy and paste the API Account ID from docusign or get it using the JWT grant example [here](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt/blob/master/example_base.py#L43)

This was probably totally my fault for not understanding it, but hopefully, this is some info that can help someone else.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution.

Answer (score 1):

do you actually replace  with a JWT token? and how did you generate this token?
 Please make sure you read and follow the instructions here - https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt

Comment: I have been using that as a reference. It is also using an outdated version of `docusign-esign` [configure_jwt_authorization_flow](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/c06e0a148d819b1c5ed815edaf92e119dd9f05fa/CHANGELOG.md#removed-1) has been replaced, which isn't too much of an issue as I used the appropriate methods. I am have copied `example_base.py` and adapted to how I am using it. Yet the result is still the same.

Comment: how did you set up your integration key?

Comment: On the admin page For Developers: API and Integration Key Information > ADD APP / INTEGRATION KEY > Implicit Grant > RSA Keypairs has been set

Comment: ok, I remember our previous thread, where the issue was the userID, I assume you have this correct this time?

Comment: how did you find out the UserID?

Comment: admin > users > API Username > UUID   Under admin > For Developers: API and Integration Key Information there is also `API Account ID`. Not sure if this necessary? I have tried different variations of what IDs I can find to use.

Comment: can you clone the code in here - https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt update your IK and url etc. and see if that works for you? that should be your starting pont

Comment: thank you for suggesting to clone and plug in values. I have to change a bit of the repo and it worked instantly. After some playing around with I found out what causes the issue. `envelope_api.create_envelope` requires the first param `account_id` which is not the user ID and not the integrator ID, but is the API Account ID. Which is obtained when using copying the flow process provided in `eg-01-python-jwt`. This was not obvious at all. There are quite a bit of IDs in place when using the API and I feel they should be reflected better on what the website provides.

Comment: docs for the method `param str account_id: The external account number (int) or account ID Guid. (required)` wasn't obvious